# Cannot add dynamic link firebase

Tags: firebase, dns, subdomain, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create my custom dynamic link: share.grabhotel.net of my custom domain : grabhotel.net. I follow these steps :
Step 1: Add URL Prefix

[image]

Step 2 : Verify domain

[image]

I passed TXT value to my DNS like this

[image]

Step 3 : Add custom domain in Firebase Hosting

[image]

Step 4 : Add A records in DNS

[image]

But when I go back to my dynamic links, I get this error

[image]

Can you show me how to fix it ? And how to add custom dynamic link successfully ? Thank you very much

Please click to the link:"[enter image description here]" for image

Comment: cant help you with your answer but firebase dynamic links has tons of bugs which just wont get fixed. Google did a poor job with it up until know. To me its nearly unusable if not totally unusable.

Answer (score 0):

In your domain registrar, the first field to the left(either Name, Host, or Alias) is set to grabhotel.net This is the root domain. You want to create dynamic links on the subdomain share.grabhotel.net. You need to set the first field to share.grabhotel.net. Also, it can take a few days for DNS records to propagate. Let me know if you need any help.